# Facebook omniauth callback and #_

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I use Rails 3.1, Devise and Omniauth.

The problem is that when facebook callbacks to my app
the url ends with `#_`. Then when in the callback action
I redirect to something - for example `/after_signin`
the redirect results in `/after_signin#_`.

Any idea how to remove this anchor from the URL?

EDIT:
It does not matter what I put in the callback function.
Even simple redirect:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < ApplicationController
  def facebook
    redirect_to "/after_callback"
  end
end
```

it would result in going to `/after_callback#_`

Even in normal controller if you go to `/#_` and you have some redirect ther
it would get redirected to the specified path with `#_` appended at the end.

EDIT2:
I just found out that it is the browser fault to preserve the anchor. So it has to be
handled in the frontend side.

Comment: Please show the code of your callback function.

Comment: that's just bizarre. why would the hash value carry through? maybe try `redirect_to "/after_callback", :anchor => ''` ?

Comment: @ben just found out that it is actually a browser fault that it preserves the anchor (Chrome and Firefox does it, Safari does not). It seemed bizarre to me as well.

Comment: This has been discussed in a previous question: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're confident that it's a browser issue, you can just use JavaScript to update the `hash` portion of the `window`'s `location` object. Maybe something like this:

```
if (window.location.hash.search('#_') >= 0) {
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```